# Why did Rand Paul vote for tobacco subsidies?

Tags: united-states, senate, subsidies

As I was recently attempting to determine which Republican presidential candidate was least in the pocket of Big Agriculture, I came across Rand Paul's record. It's [mostly strongly anti-subsidy](http://ballotpedia.org/2016_presidential_candidates_on_agricultural_subsidies) except one case where he voted against [an amendment](https://www.congress.gov/amendment/113th-congress/senate-amendment/923) that would end subsidized [crop "insurance"](http://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2011/10/27/141766762/crop-insurance-a-pricey-safety-net-for-farmers) for tobacco farmers. Since he already alienated the agro lobby with his other votes, this vote doesn't make sense to me even from a purely corrupt bargain standpoint.

Has Rand Paul ever talked about this vote and why he voted the way he did? If not, is there a procedural/strategic issue that makes this vote different, legitimate justification that applies only to subsidies for tobacco farmers (and not to the plethora of other subsidies Paul voted against), or specific tie between Rand Paul and the Tobacco lobby that could explain this one singular deviation from a strong anti cronyism record?

Comment: It could be that there are other factors affecting tobacco farmers' health.

Comment: @PointlessSpike good point, Tobacco farmers could be different. Just to be clear though, we're talking about "insurance" which gives farmers money if the price of their agricultural product drops or if there is bad weather, not health insurance.

Comment: Ah. Yes. But even then, it could be different- think about it. If they weren't given extra money, they could be driven to promote smoking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Paul's never talked about why, but it's not hard to figure out the reason.   Kentucky's the #2 tobacco growing state in the nation.    He's simply trying to get money for farmers in his state.

http://www.rockthecapital.com/03/05/top-ten-tobacco-producing-states/

Comment: AKA - subsidies are only bad when they're for other people line of thinking

Comment: I agree with this answer, but still it is speculation. We don't really know for sure what is the reason.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to properly read American bills, but from my reading of the amendment he voted down, it seems like all it did was single out tobacco producers as exempt from federal crop insurance.

All I could find of the amendment forwarded by Feinstein was this;

> The amendment is as follows:
>
> (Purpose: To prohibit the payment by the Federal Crop Insurance 
>     Corporation of any portion of the premium for a policy or plan of 
>                           insurance for tobacco)
>
> ```
>   On page 1101, between lines 5 and 6, insert the following:
>
> SEC. 11___. PROHIBITION ON PAYMENT OF PORTION OF PREMIUM BY 
>                CORPORATION FOR TOBACCO.
>
>    Section 508(e) of the Federal Crop Insurance Act (7 U.S.C. 
>  1508(e)) (as amended by section 11030(b)(2)) is amended by 
>  adding at the end the following:
>    ``(9) Prohibition on payment of portion of premium by 
>  corporation for tobacco.--
>    ``(A) In general.--Effective beginning with the 2015 
>  reinsurance year, notwithstanding any other provision of this 
>  subtitle, the Corporation shall not pay any portion of the 
>  premium for a policy or plan of insurance for tobacco under 
>  this subtitle.
>    ``(B) Deficit reduction.--Any savings realized as a result 
>  of subparagraph (A) shall be deposited in the Treasury and 
>  used for Federal budget deficit reduction.''.
> ```

Source: https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2013/05/23/senate-section/article/S3797-2

Edit: Direct link to bill, found by clicking through link

Comment: Please add a link to where you found this.

Comment: So is the implicit argument that even if he believes subsidies are bad in general, he doesn't think one kind of farmer should be singled out for political reasons?

Comment: @lazarus That is the impression I get. Though, that's mostly due to stuff he's done historically. (I may have missed something where he explained his reasoning, or simply forgotten about it)

Answer (score 3):

Tobacco is a major cash crop in his home state of Kentucky, so it benefits him politically to oppose this legislation.  But perhaps he felt that the legislation unfairly singled out one industry, rather than phase out subsidies across the board.